# Unchanged shell script arguments propagation

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The primary problem running either 32 or 64 bit binaries depending on the current platform. I have predefined set of platforms (precisely 2: 32- and 64-bit Debian, both running 64-bit kernel, but all user-space is 32- or 64-bit respectively) and >100 platform-specific binaries. All these binaries are called from my wrapper script, which is identical for all of them.

I have 2 directories: bin and tmp. In bin there are links to wrapper script and script itself. In tmp there are 2 directories: 32 and 64. In these directories executables and libraries are placed.

I've wrote the following script that relies on exported by Bash environment variable `HOSTTYPE`:

```
#!/bin/bash

executable=`basename $0`
tmp_path=$(readlink -f $(dirname $(readlink -f $0))/../tmp)

case "$HOSTTYPE" in
    i?86 )
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$tmp_path/32:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
            exec "$tmp_path/32/$executable" $@
            ;;
    x86_64 )
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$tmp_path/64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
            exec "$tmp_path/64/$executable" $@
            ;;
    * )
            echo "Unknown host type: '$HOSTTYPE'"
            ;;
esac
```

Most of the time it works as expected but it gets broken when the argument that should be quoted is passed. For example one calls

```
./some_binary --argument="\t" filename
```

where `\t` is a tab character. The script receives the pre-interpreted arguments list as:

```
./some_binary --argument=\t filename
```

Then it is reinterpreted once again in exec as

```
../tmp/32/some_binary --argument= filename
```

The tab characted get lost. How can I prevent this? Or should I solve my primary problem in a drastically different way?

Comment: Quote the `$@` expansion to prevent the shell from seeing argument-internal whitespace as something to swallow: `"$@"`.

Comment: As a general rule for the shell. Quote Everything.